# cannot import 'ParserError' from 'dateutil.parser'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to import pandas in my code and it throws the following error.

```
>>> import pandas

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/gopika/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import (
  File "/home/gopika/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/api.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas.core.algorithms import (
  File "/home/gopika/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py", line 39, in <module>
    from pandas.core.dtypes.cast import (
  File "/home/gopika/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py", line 24, in <module>
    from dateutil.parser import ParserError
ImportError: cannot import name 'ParserError' from 'dateutil.parser' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dateutil/parser/__init__.py)
```

I tried reinstalling python-dateutil but this doesn't solve the issue. I am not very sure what has changed in my enviroment but pandas was working normally and one day it suddenly start showing this error. It will be great if someone can help me with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> from dateutil.parser import ParserError
> ```

You defined, or installed, a `dateutil` module.
And it isn't this one:
https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil 2.8.2

Rename / reinstall so the `import` succeeds.

Comment: Hi @J_H, I tried "pip install python-dateutil" and it says "Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (2.7.3)". Hence I downloaded it and copied the file to "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/". But  it is still showing the same error for "from dateutil.parser import ParserError"

Comment: Oh, dear! Running python2 was a failure mode that had simply not occurred to me. Especially given the python3 tag. https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/software/python-27-reaches-end-of-life-after-20-years-of-development The PSF urges you to upgrade to 3 "as soon as you can." https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2 Does this make a difference for interoperability with modern bugfixed versions of deps like `dateutil` ? _Yes_, it does. Does it matter when you wish to receive free technical advice from random volunteers on the internet? _Yes_, definitely.